# almacenar registros en una variable tipo lista

Tags: php, laravel, lista, eloquent

Necesito generar una lista que almacene  registros de una tabla pero siempre me guarda solo el utlimo  Laravel con `ELOQUENT`.

**METODO QUE GENERA LA LISTA**

```
public function viewSec()
{

    $detalles = detalle_turno::all();
    $turnos = [];

    foreach ($detalles as $detalle) {
        if ($detalle->estado_id == 1 && $detalle->activo == TRUE) {
            $auxId = $detalle->turno_id;

            $turnos = turno::where('id', $auxId)->get();

        }
    }

    return view('turnos.panelSec', compact('turnos'));
}
```

**RUTA PARA LLAMA AL MÉTODO**

```
Route::get('/turnos/panelSec', 'turnosController@viewSec');
```

**Parte de la vista .blade**

```
    <div>

        <h1></h1>


        @if(session()->has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session()->get('message') }}
        </div>
        @endif


        <ul class="list-group">
            @foreach ($turnos as $turno)

                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $turno->numero}}{{ $turno->categoria->codigo}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $turno->categoria->descripcion}}</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

            @endforeach

        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes agregados los modelos de dichas tablas?, pudieras prescindir de ese ciclo y trabajar sobre una consulta directamente

Comment: Buenas! si los tengo .. voy a probar el metodo de utilizar solamente una consulta .. en primera medida me sirvio la solucion brindada por @Shaz. Saludos!

Comment: Yo no dí ninguna solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Es una muy mala idea el querer hacer lo que estés haciendo.

Pero te entiendo hay veces que no sabemos como solucionar un simple problema con herramientas que ya nos ofrecen, y codificamos nuestra propia solución. Por lo cual te invito a leer https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships, ya que puedes solucionar tu problema solo con una `query`.

Mientras tanto puedes crear un `collect()` que es lo mas indicado al trabajar con `laravel` y luego insertar los datos a la coleccion con `push`:

```
public function viewSec()
{

    $detalles = detalle_turno::all();
    $turnos = collect();//creamos la collection

    foreach ($detalles as $detalle) {
        if ($detalle->estado_id == 1 && $detalle->activo == TRUE) {
            $auxId = $detalle->turno_id;

            $turnos->push(turno::find($auxId));//insertas el turno que buscaste.

        }
    }

    return view('turnos.panelSec', compact('turnos'));
}
```

Comment: Aún así son muchas consultas a la base de datos para algo tan simple.

Comment: Pues estoy muy de acuerdo con @Shaz, pero el OP tendra que descubrir como mejorar su codigo.

Comment: Buenas tardes!! muchas gracias por la solucion @Shaz.. me devuelve lo que neceito, como veran soy nuevo en laravel y voy poco a poco. Intentare tambien ralizar el mismo proceso directamente con una consulta dada la realcion turno detalle. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hola debes reemplazar la línea

```
$turnos = turno::where('id', $auxId)->get();
```

Por

```
$turnos[] = turno::where('id', $auxId)->get();
```

Puedes leer más sobre arrays en https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.array.php

Comment: Intente con esa solucion pero no me funciono, pude lograrlo con collect(). Muchas gracias!